openssl3.0 cannot generate csr with TPM2 privkey on ubuntu24.04
I am configuring an AWS GreenGrass IoT device with TPM2 on ubuntu24.04 (openssl3.0.x). The instruction from AWS is bit outdated. ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/using-a-trusted-platform-module-for-endpoint-device-security-in-aws-iot-greengrass/, e.g. suppose to use -provider tpm2 with tpm2-openssl.
Below are the reference links I have tested against.

Can't get greengrass to work with TPM privkey and cert
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tpm2-pkcs11/+bug/1964975

this test exports the key with tpm2_ptool.py export, then sign with openssl. unfortunately, this is not a preferred approach, I'd like to keep the key with TPM2.
The preferred approach will be like below.
tpm2_ptool init --path=/opt/tpm2
tpm2_ptool addtoken --path=/opt/tpm2 --pid 1 --label eaptls ... #rest are pins
tpm2_ptool addkey --label="20241108_02" --path=/opt/tpm2 --key-label="AWSCredentials" ... #rest are pins

or use pkcs11-tool --keypairgen ...
openssl req -new -provider tpm2 -provider base -engine pkcs11 -keyform engine -key "pkcs11:token=eaptls;object=20241108_02;type=private" -config ./openssl.conf -subj '/CN= Greengrass Core CSR/' -out out.csr

In this approach, openssl access key through URI when generating CSR. Unfortunately, I cannot get it work.
ERROR:esys_crypto:src/tss2-esys/esys_crypto_ossl.c:723:iesys_cryptossl_pk_encrypt() ErrorCode (0x00070001) Could not create rsa key.
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/esys_iutil.c:524:iesys_compute_encrypted_salt() During encryption. ErrorCode (0x00070001)
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_StartAuthSession.c:226:Esys_StartAuthSession_Async() Error in parameter encryption. ErrorCode (0x00070001)
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_StartAuthSession.c:113:Esys_StartAuthSession() Error in async function ErrorCode (0x00070001)
ERROR: Esys_StartAuthSession: esapi:Catch all for all errors not otherwise specified
ERROR: Could not start Auth Session with the TPM.
ERROR: Error unsealing wrapping key
Login failed
Login to token failed, returning NULL...
The private key was not found at: pkcs11:token=eaptls;object=20241108_02;type=private
PKCS11_get_private_key returned NULL
Could not read private key from org.openssl.engine:pkcs11:pkcs11:token=eaptls;object=20241108_02;type=private
4047EDF186710000:error:03000096:digital envelope routines:fromdata_init:operation not supported for this keytype:../crypto/evp/pmeth_gn.c:354:
4047EDF186710000:error:42000005:PKCS#11 module:ERR_CKR_error:General Error:p11_slot.c:208:
4047EDF186710000:error:13000080:engine routines:ENGINE_load_private_key:failed loading private key:../crypto/engine/eng_pkey.c:79:

Another issue I am facing, when using p11tool to verify the key and cert.
sudo p11tool --list-all
WARNING:fapi:src/tss2-fapi/api/Fapi_List.c:228:Fapi_List_Finish() Profile of path not provisioned: /HS/SRK
ERROR:fapi:src/tss2-fapi/api/Fapi_List.c:81:Fapi_List() ErrorCode (0x00060034) Entities_List
WARNING: Listing FAPI token objects failed: "fapi:Provisioning was not executed."
Please see https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-pkcs11/blob/1.9.1/docs/FAPI.md for more details
WARNING: Getting tokens from fapi backend failed.
warning: no token URL was provided for this operation; the available tokens are:

pkcs11:model=p11-kit-trust;manufacturer=PKCS%2311%20Kit;serial=1;token=System%20Trust
pkcs11:model=SLB9665%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00;manufacturer=Infineon;serial=0000000000000000;token=

Does this mean Key generated with 'tpm2_ptool addkey' can only be listed with 'sudo tpm2_ptool listobjects'? this is a bit confusion.

In the end, I have to use "tpm2_ptool.py export", although not as expected, at least can get it  work.
